# amCharts pie - how to trigger function when mouse over a slice?

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I've tried reading the amCharts documentation and also googling, but can't seem to find the answer. I feel like I'm over thinking this...

Can someone please kindly let me know how to go about triggering a function when I have mouse over a slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're searching for the "rollOverSlice" event.
See documentation [here](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#rollOverSlice).
Usage:

```
chart.addListener("rollOverSlice", function(e) {
    // Do something.
});
```

and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L94yzuqh/).

Comment: Ok the documentation link does not work properly. It seems the documentation page has multiple occurences of elements with the same id. So you just have to scroll down and find the event i mentioned.